# LaTeXiT: increase resolution

Tags: mac, ghostscript, resolution, latexit

I'm using LaTeXiT to embed equations in my Evernote notebook. The complete package that I have includes LaTeXiT, BasicTex and GhostScript, and I configured it to produce PNG bitmap images, as recommended [here](http://maximilianchrist.com/blog/how-to-use-latex-equations-in-evernote). However, the resolution is very poor, and I wonder if there is a way to increase it.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to control the conversion to PNG with LaTeXit. An alternative would be to use the `standalone` class, which, when compiled using the `--shell-escape` option does automatic conversion. The class allows you to set the density of conversion to PNG.

Comment: You could set a scale in LaTeXiT's preferences. For example, change the scale to 400%, then open your output image in Preview and scale it to 25% *without resampling*. This will give you a 288 dpi image. If that works, you could set up an Automator droplet to handle the 25% scaling.

Comment: @AdamMaxwell it doesn't (work), unfortunately.